# CSS floats on window resize: Behavior breaks design

Tags: css, css-float

I got this CSS layout: http://www.cssdesk.com/Lgg4q

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">        
        <div class="img-wrap">
            <img src="http://unikatmag.de/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/team-dummy.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <p>Lorem</p>
            <p>ipsum</p>
        </div>

        <div class="img-wrap">
            <img src="http://unikatmag.de/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/team-dummy.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <p>Lorem</p>
            <p>ipsum</p>
        </div>

        <div class="img-wrap">
            <img src="http://unikatmag.de/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/team-dummy.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <p>Lorem</p>
            <p>ipsum</p>
        </div>        
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: grey;
    font: 18px/ Times;
    color: black;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

p { text-align: justify; }


#wrap {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: yellow;
}

.info {
    margin-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    float: left;
}


.img-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;

    float: left;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}​
```

When you resize the browser window (smaller), you can see that the behavior of the divs basically breaks the design. How to handle this problem?

My thought was to give the `#wrap` a height, but that won't work like it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it. http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/TYjd5/ (I couldn't figure out how to save the changes in cssdesk so I transfered it into jsfiddle)

Basically, I added a 'wrapper', which I called block around each of the image and info blocks. I gave them a width and floated them. This way, when the browser is resized, the info and the image always go together.

Was this the behavior you were looking for. What would you want to happen on the browser resizing?

Comment: Yep, that's the best solution I believe! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`DIV` elements don't behave well when used with percentages or I can say they are not meant to be used so. You have two options in this kind of situation:

1. Make the design of your page in such a way that it looks like it's not responding to the browser's window resize. Take as an example this very website.
2. Resize your containers accordingly when the browser's window is resized. To do this you will need to use [Media Css classes](http://thinkvitamin.com/design/getting-started-and-gotchas-of-css-media-queries/) or maybe jQuery.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into media queries. But how to make the page not responsive for window resizes? I know how to make it with text, but not with floated DIVS.

Comment: Declare a specific width and height for every container, according to your design. and if your design afford. you can use min-width/height and max-width/height accordingly

Comment: Thanks, your answer is great. I just accepted another answer because it's a bit more user friendly & modern I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min-width` on `#wrap` and set a pixel value to prevent it from breaking.